# Sequelize add existing entry as association to newly created entry and get newly created/updated entry

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

In sequelize, is there a way to add an existing entry to a newly created model and get the new model?

```
const Account = sequelize.define('Account')
const User = sequelize.define('User')

Account.associate = (models) => {
  Account.belongsToMany(models.User, { through: 'UserAccount' })
}

User.associate = (models) => {
  User.belongsToMany(models.Account, { through: 'UserAccount' })
}

Promise.all([User.create(), Account.create()])
  .spread((user, account) => account.addUsers([user.id])
  .then(userAccounts => {
     // Right now I have the userAccounts, but I want the updated account 
  }
```

Is there a clean way to do this, rather than save the promise of the Account creation and lookup the account again like the following:

```
const accountPromise = Account.create()
Promise.all([User.create(), accountPromise])
   .spread((user, account) => account.addUsers([user.id])
   .then(() => accountPromise)
   .then((account) => Account.findById(account.id, { include: 'Users' })
   .then(account) => {
      // this is what I want
   }
```

Note that I do not wish to create the User as part of the `Account.create` method. I'm simulating a User that already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I found a slightly cleaner way to implement this using async:

```
const createAccountWithUsers = async (userIds) => {
  // userIds is an array like [1, 2, 3]
  let account = await Account.create()
  await account.addUsers(userIds)
  account = await Account.findById(account.id, {include: 'Users'})

  // you now have an account object with the added user
  return account
}
```